# Re use session when using Unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am making a very simple tribal wars type of game and I use Unity for the UI instead of a browser. 
I was wondering how to keep the session alive for the whole game session after a log in was succesfull.

I made a really simple test that doesnt work.
I have an InputField that takes a string (the log in) and a button that sends to the php script the text of that InputField. the php script stores it into $_SESSION['username']. Another button just go to another page and prints $_SESSION['username'] however it says that the variable is not set.

I have tried to use session_id() but that doesn't change anything. (I may have used it wrong though..) 
I hope I made myself clear cause it is quite hard to explain.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to send the session id on each php request

Comment: and how do I apply it ? because when I did session_id(£theID); it didn't work. Is there another to set the id ?

Comment: you have to set the session id, before you call session_start

Comment: Look at the code I have posted that is what I am doing but it doesnt seem to work..

Answer (score 2):

Unity doesn't automatically handle cookies/session ids.  So, every time you get the results of www, store the cookie with the session id in playerprefs, like so:

```
if (www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey("SET-COOKIE")) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("php_cookie", www.responseHeaders["SET-COOKIE"]);
}
```

Then put the cookie string back into each request like so:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
Dictionary<string, string> headers = form.headers;
headers["Cookie"] = PlayerPrefs.GetString("php_cookie");
WWW www = new WWW("[full url]", form.data, headers);
while (www != null && !www.isDone) yield return null;
```

(I don't know if it's still the case, but I wasn't able to get it working with a normal WWW, I had to use the WWWForm to set headers. But that was a while ago.)